# How to create a symbolic link in phantomjs using fs api?

Tags: phantomjs

I am rendering some frames to PNG files in PhantomJS. I want to create a symbolic link to older frame if the frame has not changed instead of rendering it again, so as to decrease the overall rendering time.

There is no api in [fs module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/) to create a symbolic link. Any workaround or any other method to do that ?

I can use [Copy](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/copy.html) method instead of rendering but that has the overhead of disk read and write and eventually take more time than rendering.

Comment: So, have you tried suggested solution, Sachin? What have you ended up doing?

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of a simple yet effective workaround.

PhantomJS has ability to spawn/exec [child processes](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/), so we can ask OS to create symlink for us.

```
require("child_process").execFile("ln", ["-s", "source.png", "symlink.png"], null, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("execFileSTDOUT:", JSON.stringify(stdout))
    console.log("execFileSTDERR:", JSON.stringify(stderr))
});
```